# Twitter Bootstrap dismissible popover doesnot work on first click?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

My jQuery is behaving extremely weirdly. When click the button/anchor for the first time on page load it doesn't expand the popover div. But the jQuery is running and a console.log statement is executing. Only after click the button/anchor once, then clicking on something else on the page and then returning to click the button is the button performing expectedly. I am not able to make sense of this behavior. Please guide.

```
$('.BookAppButton').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Button Clicked..");
    $('.BookAppButton').popover({
        title : '',
        html : 'true',
        content:'<div><p>I should have popped on first click</p></div>'
    });
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle link. If you run the code you'll understand the weird behavior I am talking about :
http://jsfiddle.net/8yyjyte1/#&togetherjs=B36bVLS1R7

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are calling inside your click handler is meant for preparing the popover, not for showing it. You should call it outside you `.click` function, the bootstrap js will show it automatically on focus of the target, your `a` in this case.

So this is what it should look like:

```
// -- this is not needed anymore
$('.BookAppButton').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Button Clicked..");

});

// this should be directly in your 'ready' function
$('.BookAppButton').popover({
    title: '',
    html: 'true',
    content: '<div><p>I should have popped on first click</p></div>'
});
```

and the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cewkazk6/

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm :)